# Nightwatch parallel for two browser run only default for browserstack

Tags: nightwatch.js, browserstack

I have configured several test settings and I want to run parallel chrome and ie.
When I run

> ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env chrome

test for chrome runs

> ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env ie

test for ie runs

> ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env ie,chrome

test for firefox runs (as I guess this run only default ones and nothing more)

Nightwatch 1.0.18

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "test"
  ],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "live_output" : true,
  "custom_commands_path": "config/commands",
  "test_runner": {
    "type" : "mocha",
    "options" : {
      "grep": "@acc"
    }
  },

  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "selenium_host": "hub-cloud.browserstack.com",
      "selenium_port": 80,
      "launch_url": "localhost",
      "browserstack.key": "KEY",
      "browserstack.user": "USER",
      "browserstack.local": "true"
    },

    "chrome-local": {
      "default_path_prefix": "",
      "launch_url": "localhost",
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "on_failure": true,
        "on_success": true,
        "on_error": true,
        "path": "./screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "chromeOptions": {
          "args": [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "headless",
            "window-size=1920,1200"
          ]
        },
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
        "elementScrollBehavior": 1
      }
    },
    "chrome": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browser": "chrome"
      }
    },
    "ie": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "ie",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for running parallel tests using Nightwatch refer -  https://github.com/browserstack/nightwatch-browserstack

As you need to run parallel tests on Chrome and IE browsers you need to make changes to the line https://github.com/browserstack/nightwatch-browserstack/blob/master/package.json#L10 as follows-

> "parallel": "./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch -c conf/parallel.conf.js
>   -e ie,chrome"

Comment: As you can see everything is the same. Nightwatch is run with -e  (--env) param, I run it with Browserstack username and key and so one...

With version 0.9 it works fine, after upgrade parallel stop working.

Comment: Also this github repo is for "nightwatch": "^0.8.18" not for the latest. So it it useless